# Are test assemblies published

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Are test assemblies deployed when publishing a webapp to azure? I thought they were built on the build server and executed on the build server. But when the publish happens - only required code and assemblies make it to the webserver.

We have a service that detects code that is flagged as a security risk within a test. So just trying to see if that code ever makes it to production.

Comment: If there's any doubt, you can view the contents of your web app at https://[appservicename].scm.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: You're asking the wrong question, if static code analysis including security analysis tools detect problems the code _should not even have been compiled_ let alone deployed

Comment: There are strings that are being tested against our authentication api which we want to filter. These strings are being detected by a GitHub tool - correctly. But they are within the unit test project. So we know they are bad. We need them there. We just want to be sure that it’s safe and the code cannot be executed in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# we usually kepp test in seprate project and as this if your main projects don't reference them then you will not find test dll's on App Service. But if some of your projects reference some test projects or test libraries you should rather refactor your code base to get rid off such dependencies.